# How to update a test run in HP ALM via c#?

Tags: c#

I can get connected to HP ALM via c# OTA no problem.  It's what is supposed to happen next that isn't clear.  I have looked all over HPs documentation for OTA but not much there in regards to updating a test run.

I can make a connection to ALM no problem. I then create a TestSetFactory and RunFactory.  I don't know what to do from here.  I'm trying to add a run for a particular test set in ALM.  I want to add a run and set it to either Pass or Fail and add a comment.

```
TestSetFactory tsFactory = (TestSetFactory)qcConn.TestSetFactory;
RunFactory runFactory = (RunFactory)qcConn.RunFactory();
```

Does anyone know how to do this?  Is there a previous post that I can't find?  Please give me the link and I will happily go there.

If anyone else has figured this out can you please post your code?

Comment: So, basically no one knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after much trial and error I figured it out.  I'm sure there are easier ways to do it but I haven't figured them out yet.

To create a run and update it's status and that of it's steps here's what you need to run:

```
//This assumes you are already connected to ALM and your project.

string testFolder = @"Root\whatever your folder name is";                    

TestSetFactory tstFactory = (TestSetFactory)qcConn.TestSetFactory;
TestSetTreeManager tsTreeMgr = (TestSetTreeManager)qcConn.TestSetTreeManager;
TestSetFolder tsFolder = (TestSetFolder)tsTreeMgr.get_NodeByPath(testFolder);
List tsList = tsFolder.FindTestSets("MyTestSet", false, null);

foreach (TestSet ts in tsList)
{
    TestSetFolder tstFolder = (TestSetFolder)ts.TestSetFolder;
    TSTestFactory tsTestFactory = (TSTestFactory)ts.TSTestFactory;
    List mylist = tsTestFactory.NewList("");
    foreach (TSTest tsTest in mylist)
    {
        RunFactory runFactory = (RunFactory)tsTest.RunFactory;
        Run run = (Run)runFactory.AddItem("Name of your run here");
        run.CopyDesignSteps();
        run.Status = "Passed";
        run.Post();

        StepFactory stepFactory = (StepFactory)run.StepFactory;
        dynamic stepList = stepFactory.NewList("");
        var rstepList = (TDAPIOLELib.List)stepList;
        foreach (dynamic rstep in rstepList)
        {
            rstep.Status = "Passed";
            rstep.Post();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose anyone can figure out how to attach a file to a test run?